# php script can't send headers because headers have already been sent, but are characters outside the script

Tags: php, header

This are my first two lines:

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: application/x-javascript');
```

And it gives me the headers already sent in line 1.

It is intended to generate a JavaScript file that loads from an HTML page, when checked the JavaScript file from Firebug i got the following file:

```
1  ï»¿<br />
2  <b>Warning</b>: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at C:\Program Files\Apache Group\Apache2\htdocs\totoro\Js\libs.php:1) in <b>C:\Program Files\Apache Group\Apache2\htdocs\totoro\Js\libs.php</b> on line <b>1</b><br />
3  var Totoro = {}, $t = Totoro;
```

As you can see, it spits a character that looks like garbage characters, but nothing is sended, the first line is a `header` function call. What might be the problem?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You have most probably saved the file as UTF-8 with [BOM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte-order_mark) (Byte-order mark), resave it as UTF-8 without said thingy.

Answer (score 7):

This character sequence is the [UTF-8 BOM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte-order_mark#Representations_of_byte_order_marks_by_encoding). When using UTF-8, save your files without BOM (sometimes also called signature).

Additionally you should declare the encoding you’re using. Because as the UTF-8 BOM is shown as the characters you named, your data is probably interpreted with ISO 8859-1, as the UTF-8 BOM byte sequence 0xEFBBBF represents the characters `ï` (0xEF), `»` (0xBB) and `¿` (0xBF) in ISO 8859-1.

So remove the BOM and use this `Content-Type` header field along with the correct MIME type `application/javascript` and `charset` parameter:

```
Content-Type: application/javascript;charset=utf-8
```

Answer (score 0):

I foudn this on wikipedia:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte-order_mark#Representations_of_byte_order_marks_by_encoding

This made me change the preferences of my Komodo editor an there is a "Encoding: use signature (BOM)" checked. Once unchecked the problem is solved.